# How can i add an expression to jcr sql2 query?

Tags: java, aem, jcr-sql2

I have query

```
SELECT * 
FROM [cq:ReplicationStatus] AS node 
WHERE (ISDESCENDANTNODE(node,'/home/users/we-retail') 
  AND node.[rep:authorizableId] = ${userId})
```

and I have a function

```
public HashMap<String, Object> getInformation(Integer userId) throws IOException, RepositoryException 
{
     ... 
}
```

where I execute my query. But it does not work, because `${userId}` is a string not an expression. I also tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM [cq:ReplicationStatus] AS node 
WHERE (ISDESCENDANTNODE(node,'/home/users/A') 
  AND node.[rep:authorizableId] = '\"+userId+\"')"
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you right:

```
public HashMap<String, Object> getInformation(Integer userId) throws 
       IOException, RepositoryException 
{
     String sqlQueryStr = "SELECT * FROM [cq:ReplicationStatus] AS node
     WHERE (ISDESCENDANTNODE(node,'/home/users/A') AND 
     node.[rep:authorizableId] = '"+userId+"')";
     ... 
}
```

should work.